# Flutter app does not work on some devices

Tags: android, flutter

i develop mobile app by flutter,but release apk of my app does not work or install on some devices for example samsung a10, p.s it works on some devices for example(s10 plus or xiaomi note7 pro), how can i find what is issue?

Comment: `"app does not work or install"`- what do you mean by that? what are the symptoms?

Comment: Can you Please add the screenshot of the issue that are showing on the device side once you try to install the app on device.

Comment: i send apk by bluetooth and try to install on received device but i see error -app can not install, i will send screenshots

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: my observations tell me that, if app has sign in config as Debug(i use flutter run --release) does not work in phones which's developer mode is disable